# How to get TAB event in Internet Explorer 8 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an application which had developed according to IE6.
Now Because of IE8 tabbing features not the application have been start giving problem.
The Problem is that,
if I have opened first context in "tab1" and then open second context in "tab2".
Now when I back to "tab1" and refresh the page then it loads the second context that is new one.

This is logically correct but I want to block the user while opening the second tab so that user restrict to only first tab.

So I have been come to conclusion that we can do this with JavaScript by getting some tab event, but I am not too much familiar with JavaScript.

Please tell me is there any solution if you have in your mind for above problem,
or tell me is there any way so that we can catch the tab event.

Comment: How is this problem new? Wouldn't you have the same problem with the second "context" (what ever that is) be opened in a second *window*, too?

Comment: You can face same problem in 2nd window.

Comment: In IE8 it shares same session.I want stop TAb and 2nd window

Comment: You can't stop a user to open a new tab or window. BTW, tabs and windows are the same thing in a web application, they can' be distinguished. Web applications need be be designed in a way, that they don't break, if opened in multiple tabs/windows.

Answer (score 0):

Praise all things glorious: There is **no** way to prevent a user from opening a new tab. In Firefox, you can cruelly prevent a user from using keyboard shortcuts to open a new tab by returning `false` from an `input` element's `onkeypress` event, but it's still possible to open a new tab otherwise.

The solution? Well, from what you're saying, it sounds as though you're using the session to store the user's current page (and, well, most everything else, but that's another story). Having spent a lot of time using a web application that was built that way, I can tell you firsthand: don't do this! The web already has a wonderful method for storing the user's current page: the URL.